# nugetPackages .netcore 3.0 missing in another machine

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I have built a .netcore3.0 project on one machine and then transferred it to **another standalone machine**.

I copied all of the "Nugets" to "programFiles(x86)\Microsoft SDK's\nugetPackages"

the .csproj file includes the packageReference but when building the project I get the Errors:

```
Unable to find package <packageName> .No package exist with this id in source(s):
Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages
```

also running CLI command dotnet list package returns: "[netcoreapp3.0]No packages were found for this framework."

does anybody know how to copy the nugetPackages with the folder itself like I Know you can do in .net Framework?

Comment: See NuGet's docs on hosting your own feed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview.  You then need a nuget.config file with your source code that adds your private feed as a package source.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind `nuget` and similar dependency systems, is that list of packages is centralized and part of project. In that way when you copy your source code (including your list of packages) you only need to restore/install them (note that the list of packages are not the packages itself)

On the machine where you are having this issue run one of these commands

- nuget restore
- dotnet restore

It will retreive all the packages from its source and install it, you do not need to copy the actual packages, it was not designed to work that way

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore

Comment: thank you, but what about stand alone project

Comment: If you are working on two separate computers is no longer a "stand alone" project, upload your project to a private git repository and restore it on the other end - also check the comment on your question about a nuget.config file